# Google API getSignedUrl responseDisposition does nothing

Tags: html, node.js, gcloud

Using Google API on NodeJS I do something like

```
const [url] = await mybucket.file('myfiles/uniquefileid').getSignedUrl({
  action: 'write',
  contentType: 'image/png',
  expires: dayjs().add(1, 'hour').toDate(),  
  responseDisposition: 'attachment; filename="myfile.png"',
  version: 'v4'  
});
```

Within the returned URL I see `..&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%27file.png%27`

So it's doing the right thing there. Then I upload the file on the front end via Axios. Now when I retrieve this file using an HTML component like `<a href="fullpath" download />` it still downloads with the unique file id instead of the filename. I inspect the headers of the file (I open it in a new tab) and I don't see any `Content-Disposition` on the response header. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to configure Gcloud to use this header somewhere?

Comment: 1) verify that you do not already have `Content-Disposition` set on the object metadata. 2) Add the query parameter `response-content-disposition=attachment; filename="myfile.png"` (URL encode) to the Signed URL when making the client (Axios) request. See this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#responsecontentdisposition).